# How to setup nginx config in AWS loadbalancer for NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, reverse-proxy

I have been struggling with multiple iterations of NGINX config files to run a NodeJS app on EC2 instance in AWS. But I'm not succeeding. Any help would be appreciated.

My requirements:

`http` requests must be forced to `https`.

`www.example.com` should be redirected to `example.com`

I was able to make it work in `http` and `https` separately.

www to non-www is not working at all.

I commented the logic I used to force `http` to `https`

If I uncomment it, I keep getting `OutOfService` error in LoadBalancer.

My NGINX config code:

```
server {

 listen       80;
 listen       443;

 server_name example.com;

 root  /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vdc_live;


 location /  {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


  # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  # if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' )
  # {
  #    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  # }


}


server
{
   server_name www.example.com.com;
   return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> http requests must be forced to https.

If you are already using LB then better to use redirect feature of LB?

[image]

> With redirect actions, the load balancer can redirect incoming
>   requests from one URL to another URL. This includes the capability to
>   redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS requests, which allows you to meet
>   your compliance goal of secure browsing, achieve better search ranking
>   and high SSL/TLS score for your site. You can also use redirects to
>   send users to a different web site such as redirecting from an old
>   version of an application to a new version.

[support-for-redirects-and-fixed-responses-for-application-load-balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/elastic-load-balancing-announces-support-for-redirects-and-fixed-responses-for-application-load-balancer/)

The above work fine, if you are using classic LB then you can check [redirect-http-https-elb](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/)

> www.example.com should be redirected to example.com

You can also do this using LB, you can do this using `host` based routing. you check further [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html)

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to find the option to edit Rules in Load Balancer. I'm getting options only to change Load Balancer Protocol/ Load Balancer Port/ Instance Protocol / Instance Port

Comment: Which lb you are using

Comment: Classic Load Balancer

Comment: CLB i.e classic load balancer's doen't have these options.

Comment: @error404 what could be my best possible solution in this case?

Comment: If you are using classic load balancr then you can check link provided in answer and second thing if you are in testing phase I'll recommend to go with applications load balancr, even AWS not recommended to use classic they recommend to use network lb if applications not suitable in some cases